# Service stopping after some time Android 10

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to create service that plays music in background. Everything works fine, except that the service is stopping after some time when the phone is locked. To be exact - my service logic looks like that:
after pressing start it plays music (playNext function is called), when the music ends the playNext function is called again. For some time it works perfectly, but when the phone is locked after a few songs, the song is ending and the next one is not starting until I press any physical button to wake up the phone.
The service is being run in foreground with a Notification, onStartCommand returns START_STICKY.
I'm using Android 10, my phone is Xiaomi Mi A2 lite.
As far as I remember issues like that weren't happening to me before - is it some new 'feature' in Android10 to workaround? And how to do that if yes? Or maybe it's my phone model problem and nothing can be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a reason.

The problem is with my phone. After upgrade to android 10 there are some bugs (for example different music players are spontaneously pausing music).